# spec file db vs spec'd code db disconnect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, devise

I'm trying to clean up a projects specs, however I'm running into an odd issue. I have a simple sign up test(using devise). What's going on is anything created in the db is not persisting across the entire spec. So If I create a user in the spec file that user will not show up in the controller and vice versa. Devise is creating the User and saving it. I first I thought maybe they were hitting different db's or using transactions. did this simple output from each spec file and spec'd code(the controller).

```
puts Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.open_transactions
```

but both are coming back with the same thing.

```
{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>15000, "port"=>5432, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"db_name_test"}
0
```

DatabaseCleaner is being used to clean the db, that's basically following the standard setup.

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

**update**

checked threads, there are a total of 8, only one running at a time, but the object hash is different. Does that matter?

```
- spec file - 
#<Thread:0x007f208444e660>
- specd code - 
#<Thread:0x007f2088a075d0>
```

any config options I should check or thoughts?

Comment: Is any of your code running in a different thread?

Comment: humm will check that any thought on how?

Comment: @Slicedpan see update